# osm geopoint routing offline

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, offline, geopoints

Good afternoon,

I'm an Android Developer and i'm trying to create an app with osm. At this point i'm stil running some tests and i managed to create a map of Lisbon, Portugal with Mobile Atlas Creator. With the GEMF file i've loaded the map and now i'm trying to create a routing system. What i've learned is that the GEMF file is "simply" a lot of pictures and it doenst create routes.

I've created a route with the osmbonuspack_v3.4 but i had to insert manualy all the GeoPoint's of a street and its GeoPoint's of curve (for example) for it to draw a good route. It's s still a very far-fetched version because i'm still learning, but i managed to do something.

My question is: is there any way of generating the GeoPoints without having to insert theme all manualy? Is there any kind of OSM Map that has an attached DataBase of GeoPoint's? If not, is there any way of creating the GeoPoint's at the same time that i create the map (like i did in the MOBAC)?

what i want is to create my own route. i dont want to find the fastest route to a certain location.

Thanks for you'r help

Cheers

Ricardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of these *GEMF files*. They certainly don't officially belong to OpenStreetMap.

If you want raw geodata for routing then just [download](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) it from OSM (also look at the [extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts)). You should read about [OSM's basic elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [OSM tags for routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing).

There is also an extensive wiki page about [routing with OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) including a list of various [online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers), a really large list of [OSM software and libraries for Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) as well as for [other mobile devices](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software#Mobile_Devices) of which are many open source. This should be enough to get an idea where to start.

Comment: I've been reading the [extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) and i think that the third link have what i want. i'll just have to read some more, but i think you've answered my question.

tanks

Comment: Hi, i've download the raw geodata. i have the osm file that i want. i'm stuck now because i dont know how to use it in an android app. Can you help me? is there a lib to interact with osm or osm.pbf files for android?

Comment: What's wrong with the links I posted about OSM on Android and routing software/libraries?

Comment: Well i understood how the OSM files are structured. The have nodes, ways and relations. I've constructed the osm file that corresponds to the city that i want. i've been reading about the osmbonuspack for routing, and i've dowloaded osmnavigator source code to learn how should be loaded an osm file, but in their example they use an osm file with 700kb, mine has 99MB. i can t load that osm file. i dont know how to work with an OSM file. i cant understand how can an osm file be used to route

Comment: I suggest to create a separate question for this issue. I'm not familiar with osmnavigator or the mentioned osmbonuspack.

Comment: witch tecnology would you advise to me for an offline routing development app for android?

Comment: Take a look at [Gosmore](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Gosmore), [GraphHopper](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GraphHopper), [Navit](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Navit), [Osmand](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmAnd) or any of the other tools and libraries listed on the mentioned wiki pages.